# Enforce resource limit on user session for a c program

Tags: c, shell, malloc, buffer

I have a binary. I want to set limit to the resources available to that binary when executed.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. But `malloc` will allocate memory from the heap, not the stack. If all you want is to execute the code inside the `if` why not simply change that code to: `if(1) { ... whatever ... }`?

Comment: Oh! But I dont have permission to change the code as well. Is there a way to limit heap usage?

Comment: Do you intend to free the memory if you allocation does succeed? Surely you'll want to put the address in a variable and do something with it?

Comment: See I have the compiled form of above code only (with debugging option) I cant change the code. I am working on linux btw

Comment: You mean you want the `if` condition to fail?

Comment: no I want the If condition to pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use

```
 uname -v [Memory in KB]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want, but you can set the amount of memory available to `malloc` like this:

```
    struct rlimit s;
    int ret = getrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &s);  // 0 on success
    s.rlim_cur = s.rlim_max;
    ret = setrlimit(RLIMIT_DATA, &s);
```

That would allow the process its maximum memory for data. But if the maximum has already been set low in the process, a normal user cannot increase it again.

Comment: I cant do that as I said earlier that i only have binary file.